# Instantiate error related to path.combine

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[image]

[image]

Here is the codes:

```
 private void CreatePlayer()
    {
        Debug.Log("Creating Player");
        PhotonNetwork.Instantiate(Path.Combine("PhotonPrefabs", "PhotonPlayer"),
            Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity);  
    }
```

And There is the error:PhotonNetwork.Instantiate() can only instantiate objects with a PhotonView component. This prefab does not have one: PhotonPrefabs\PhotonPlayer

So my question is :How to solve the error ? I am confused since I thought I have instantiated it but it seemed not to work .As there is no ways to create a game object (not prefab) like capsule within the folder inside the project window. Did I make a path correctly for `path.combine` ?

Thank you for your patience and hope there's someone who can help me.Your help is greatly appreciated !  If there is any misunderstanding , it is welcomed to tell me and I give more detail of it .Thanks

edit: the first pic show no error and function properly .The second one(mine) can't function .

Comment: Try using `PhotonNetwork.Instantiate("PhotonPrefabs/PhotonPlayer",
            Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity);`  If it follows the same rules as `Resources.Load`, you should always use the `/` character for the path separator.

Comment: I tried it  , and the error still comes out

Comment: Oh, the second pic is your situation. Thank you for editing that in. The error tells you that your prefab does not have a `PhotonView` component. And in that picture, it very plainly shows that there is no Photon View component in the root of that prefab. Consider adding a Photon View component to it.

Comment: @Ruzihm It does works! Thx ! Sorry for late reply , also , how can I make a capsule (not prefab) inside the folder of PhotonPrefabs  for which in the first pic

Answer (score 0):

The prefab needs a Photon View component.

The prefab in the first pic looks like it has a child capsule. Right click on your prefab and create a 3D capsule object.